# Is there a method to proof real inequalites like $f(x_0, x_1, ..., x_n)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can i use the axioms for proof all inequalities mechanically?, is logic because axioms are in all inequalities but they are hidden, a method to proof like use mechanically the axioms for all inequalities for example all inequalities can proof with:

1. Trichotomy
2. if $a ≤ b$ then $a + c ≤ b + c$
3. if $0 ≤ a$ and $0 ≤ b$ then $0 ≤ a b$
4. Transitivity
5. Identity

but how can I mechanize?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $x^5 -10x + 2 \geq 0$ is quite difficult to solve mechanically.

Comment: Yes, there is an algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers, but I don't think it is practical.